# How to connect an Arduino Uno Wifi Developer's Edition to PHP

Tags: php, firebase, arduino, arduino-uno

I want to send data from my arduino uno wifi to PHP which in turn sends the value to Firebase. The PHP code works since I can manually send data to the database from my browser. However, I am not able to do so from the arduino uno wifi.

Here are my codes:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <UnoWiFiDevEd.h>

void setup() {
  Wifi.begin();
  Wifi.println("REST Server is up");
}

void loop() {
  while(Wifi.available()){
    process(Wifi);
  }
  delay(50);
}

void process(WifiData client){
  client.println("POST /xxx.php?value=22.00 HTTP/1.1");
  client.println("HOST: xxx.xxx.com");
  client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  client.println();
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you'll need a call to [`client.connect`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ClientConnect) as well as just printing a host header. It doesn't know where to send the data otherwise.

Comment: It actually throws this error when I call client.connect:  'class WifiData' has no member named 'connect'

Answer (score 0):

Look at the RestClient example of UnoWiFiDevEd library. You must use Ciao object to send a request. (The example doesn't work because arduino.org is off)

If you find out that the UnoWiFiDevEd library and the factory firmware of Uno WiFi are very limited, strange and slow, you can change the firmware to WiFi Link and use the general networking WiFi Link library with [Uno WiFi Serial1](https://github.com/jandrassy/UnoWiFiDevEdSerial1/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: I changed the firmware to WiFi Link. I succesfully connected it to my network from the configuration panel on my browser. I tried to run some examples, they are compiling and uploading fine. However nothing shows up in the serial monitor. Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX9Hz.jpg

Comment: I see you have an example from the Library Manager version of WiFi Link library (1.0.1). Which version of WiFi Link did you install? Did you use Serial1 library and the WiFi Link firmware version 1.1.0 linked in readme.md? Then use the github version of the WiFi Link library too. There are modified examples. Everything is in my [github repositories](https://github.com/jandrassy)

Comment: I had installed the WiFi Link v1.0.1 directly from the IDE... I deleted it manually from the libraries folder but I can still see it in Files>Examples and Sketch>Libraries from the IDE.
Other weird things I noticed:
(1) I added the library from your git repo to my libraries folder but I cant see it in the IDE
(2) Every time I reconnect the board to my PC, I have to switch it from AP+STA to STA
(3) I can't upload sketches OTA, I get the error message: Failed to reset the board, upload failed An error occurred while uploading the sketch

Comment: 1) after putting a library into library folder, you must restart the IDE to see it in ID

Comment: 2) let it in AP+STA - it is no remembered (arduino.org didn't implement it and neither did I yet) 3) the basic version of WiFi Link firmware doesn't support sketch OTA upload (how-to is in readme.md last chapters)

Comment: The examples from the git repo don't show anything in the Serial Monitor as well :( This is so frustrating as this is my first arduino project

Comment: try the WiFiLinkWebClient example from UnoWiFiDevEdSerial1 library. the examples in WiFi link library are not specialized for Uno WiFi